# How to default column to default value / value of another column if no matching row in SQL Left Join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table Table_A with a name and a field named type_and_cargo. The following Postgresql query uses a left join to get the separate "type" and "cargo" values from Table_B

```
SELECT 
a.type_and_cargo,
a.name
b.type_and_cargo,
b.type,
b.cargo FROM table_A a
LEFT JOIN table_B b USING (type_and_cargo)
```

But some rows in Table_A have a type_and_cargo which does not have a corresponding value in Table_B. Right now, the "type" and "cargo" columns become Null. How can I assign the a.type_and_cargo to "type" and Unknown to "cargo" if not match exists?

Comment: use 'isnull' function. Like 'isnull(b.type,'your desire value').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this do it?

```
SELECT 
  a.type_and_cargo,
  a.name
  b.type_and_cargo,
  CASE
    WHEN b.type_and_cargo IS NULL THEN a.type_and_cargo
    ELSE b.type
  END as type,
  CASE
    WHEN b.type_and_cargo IS NULL THEN 'Unknown'
    ELSE b.cargo
  END as cargo
FROM table_A a
  LEFT JOIN table_B b USING (type_and_cargo)
```

Comment: Good answer. Evaluating the joined column is more accurate than using `coalesce`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I needed. One small correction - you need a comma after the "END as type", otherwise it gives an error.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected the answer accordingly.